# How to update the Repeatable fields in Joomla 3 with jQuery

Tags: repeatable-field

I have looked in the `/media/system/js/repeatable-uncompressed.js` file but could only find events that trigger after the init of JRepeatable.

Is there a way to update the input value of the repeatable field, and then initialize a new draw or build of the repeatable fields based on the new values.

To update the value of the repeatable field is easy:

```
var fer = '{"key":["1","38","3","13","23"],"cpe":["3","2","3","3","2"],"mbr":["3","2","3","3","2"],"mtr":["3","2","3","2","2"]}';
jQuery('#jform_repeatable_id').val(fer);
```

But to get it to initialize based on those new values is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

By default Repeatable initialised on `load` event, so you have time to change the value on `ready` event, that occurs before `load` event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#jform_repeatable_id').val('json string of your new value');
})
```

Comment: I need to change the values some time later when the user clicks on another field.

Comment: hm, unfortunately I do not see a way to do this .. you still can set `jQuery('#jform_repeatable_id').val('json string of your new value')` but it will not affect existing instance, and can be reseted ...